# Azure: one VM with two services on two NICs with two public IPs

Tags: azure, networking, load-balancing, nic

### Setup

I am setting up an Azure VM (Standard E2as_v4 running Debian 10) to serve multiple services. I want to use a separate public IP address for each service. To test whether I can do this, I set up the following:

```yaml
vm1
 - nic1
  - vnet1, subnet1
  - ipconfig1: 10.0.1.1 <-> p.0.0.1
  - nsg1
    - allow: ssh (22)
 - nic2
  - vnet1, subnet2
  - ipconfig2: 10.0.2.1 <-> p.0.0.2
  - nsg2
    - allow: http (80)

vnet1
 - subnet1: 10.0.1.0/24
 - subnet2: 10.0.2.0/24
 - address space: [10.0.1.0/24, 10.0.2.0/24]
```

Where `10.x.x.x` IPs are private and `p.x.x.x` IPs are public.

`nic1` (network interface) and its accompanying `nsg1` (network security group) were created automatically when I created the VM; otherwise they are symmetrical to `nic2`, `nsg2` (except for `nsg2` allowing HTTP rather than SSH). Also, both NICs register fine on the VM.

### Problem

I can connect to SSH via the public IP on `nic1` (`p.0.0.1`). However, I fail to connect to HTTP via the public IP on `nic2` (`p.0.0.2`).

### Things I've tried

*Listening on 0.0.0.0.* To check whether it is a problem with my server, I had my HTTP server listen on `0.0.0.0`. Then I allowed HTTP on `nsg1`, and added a secondary IP configuration on `nic1` with another public IP (static `10.0.1.101 <-> p.0.0.3`). I added the static private IP address manually in the VM's configuration (`/run/network/interfaces.d/eth0`; possibly not the right file to edit but the IP was registered correctly). I was now able to connect via both public IPs associated with `nic1` (`p.0.0.1` and `p.0.0.3`) but still not via `nic2` (`p.0.0.2`). **This means I successfully set up two public IPs for two different services on the VM, but they share the same NIC.**

*Configuring a load-balancer.* I also tried to achieve the same setup using a load balancer. In this case I created a load balancer with two backend pools - `backend-pool1` for `nic1` and `backend-pool2` for `nic2`. I diverted SSH traffic to `backend-pool1` and HTTP traffic to `backend-pool2`. The results were similar to the above (SSH connected successfully, HTTP failed unless I use `backend-pool1` rather than `backend-pool2`). I also tried direct inbound NAT rules - with the same effect.

*Check that communication via subnet works.* Finally, I created a VM on `subnet2`. I can communicate with the service using the private IP (`10.0.2.1`) regardless of the NSG configuration (I tried a port which isn't allowed on the NSG and it passed). However, it doesn't work when I use the public IP (`p.0.0.2`).

### Question

What am I missing? Is there a setting I am not considering? What is the reason for not being able to connect to my VM via a public IP address configured on an additional NIC?

### Related questions

- [Configuring a secondary NIC in Azure with an Internet Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442774/configuring-a-secondary-nic-in-azure-with-an-internet-gateway) - the answer refers to creating a secondary public IP
- [Multiple public IPs to Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633715/multiple-public-ips-to-azure-vm/34729974) - the answer refers to creating a load balancer

Notes: I can try to provide command lines to recreate the setup, if this is not enough information. The HTTP server I am running is:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 10.0.2.1:80:80 nginx
```

And I replaced to listen on `0.0.0.0` for subsequent tests.

Here's the final topology I used for testing.

[image: Topology I used for testing, described above]

Answer (score 1):

To allow the secondary interface (with a public IP) to access to or from the Internet, we don't need to create a load balancer. Instead, we can use **iproute** to maintain multiple routing tables. Read http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-adv-routing.php and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59112745/access-internet-with-second-or-multiple-nic-in-azure) for more details.

After my validation, you can add the following configurations and It was working on Linux (ubuntu 18.04) VM for me.

1. Activate Linux advanced routing on a Debian GNU/Linux system, install the `iproute` package:

   `apt-get install iproute`
2. Configure two default routes

   `echo 2 cheapskate >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables`
3. Add the new default route to table **cheapskate** and then display it:

   `~# ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1 table cheapskate`

   `~# ip route show table cheapskate`

   `default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth1`
4. Add a rule for when a packet has a from pattern of 10.0.2.4 in which case the routing table **cheapskate** should be used with a priority level of 1000.

   `ip rule add from 10.0.2.4 lookup cheapskate prio 1000`

The kernel searches the list of ip rules starting with the lowest priority number, processing each routing table until the packet has been routed successfully.

After all of this, you can check it with the following command, you will see the public IP address attached to the secondary interface.

```
curl --interface eth1 api.ipify.org?format=json -w "\n"
```

Please note you have enough permission to do all of the above steps.

[image]